# How to fix Express.js and @nestjs/core vulnerabilities in a fresh NestJS project without introducing breaking changes?

Tags: express, nestjs

I've just initiated a new project with NestJS and upon running npm audit, I encountered some moderate severity vulnerabilities related to both `express` and `@nestjs/core`

The vulnerabilities are:

- Express.js Open Redirect in malformed URLs - [GHSA-rv95-896h-c2vc](https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-rv95-896h-c2vc)
- @nestjs/core Information Exposure via StreamableFile pipe - [GHSA-4jpv-8r57-pv7j](https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-4jpv-8r57-pv7j)

Here are the relevant parts of the `npm audit` output:

```
@nestjs/core  <9.0.5
Severity: moderate
fix available via `npm audit fix --force`
Will install @nestjs/core@10.3.5, which is a breaking change
node_modules/@nestjs/core
  @nestjs/testing  <=9.0.0-next.2
  Depends on vulnerable versions of @nestjs/core
  node_modules/@nestjs/testing

express  <4.19.2
Severity: moderate
No fix available
node_modules/express
  @nestjs/platform-express  *
  Depends on vulnerable versions of express
  node_modules/@nestjs/platform-express
```

For `@nestjs/core`, running `npm audit fix --force` will install `@nestjs/core@10.3.5`, introducing a potential breaking change. Additionally, there appears to be no fix available for the Express.js vulnerability.

- How can I fix these vulnerabilities without the risk of introducing breaking changes due to forced updates?
- Is there a way to patch these security issues while maintaining my current versions, or is upgrading the only option?
- How critical is it to address these vulnerabilities immediately in the context of a new development environment?

Any assistance or recommendations on managing these vulnerabilities without compromising the stability of the application would be immensely helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR**: Use [`overrides`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/configuring-npm/package-json#overrides) to override the nested dependency.

---

As the message says, the Express team [had patched `express` in the version 4.19.2 of the package](https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-rv95-896h-c2vc). If you are using `express` directly, update it to the version `4.19.2` or higher.

If your dependencies (namely, `@nestjs/platform-express`) use unpatched `express`, you must **override the nested dependency using npm's [`overrides`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/configuring-npm/package-json#overrides) field** (available since `npm` CLI version 8.13.0). Keep in mind that once the NestJS team updates `@nestjs/platform-express` by using the patched version of `express`, you should remove the override.

1. Install the patched version of `express`:

```bash
npm install express@4.19.2
```

2. Add the override instruction in package.json:

```json
{
  "name": "my-package",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "4.19.2"
  },
  "overrides": {
    "express": "$express"
  }
}
```

3. Reinstall dependencies, for them to pick up the changes:

```bash
npm ci
# or `npm install` if you don't have the lockfile; consider using a lockfile
```

You can then run `npm ls express` to see the dependency tree.

---

If you are using `express` directly in your package and you don't want to mix the `express` that you use with the `express` that your dependencies use, consider installing the patched version under an alias:

```bash
npm install express-patched-CVE-2024-29041@npm:express@4.19.2
#           { alias                      }     { known package name and version }
```

```json
{
  "name": "my-package",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "3.1415926",
    "express-patched-CVE-2024-29041": "npm:express@4.19.2"
  },
  "overrides": {
    "@nestjs/platform-express": {
      "express": "$express-patched-CVE-2024-29041"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the comprehensive guide on how to override a nested dependency with the patched version of express!  — great tip! Thanks again for sharing your knowledge.

Comment: @Parzh, very helpful. Useful knowledge for future too.